# Slightly Slow Approval to the Gallery, non-removal of existing script

Tags: google-apps-script

So, I have to make a minor bug fix to all of my scripts: I didn't realize there was a limit to the amount you could push into the Cache (BTW Google, I'm pretty sure this isn't documented anywhere).

Anyhow, so my three line fix resulted in my having to resubmit a bunch of scripts.  Typically this isn't a big deal, Google is usually super awesome about approving them (usually the next business day).  However, unfortunately they seem to be taking more time this time.  This became a problem because I had to do a presentation today, and I just assumed they would be approved by now (I fudged it and just showed a spreadsheet with the script already installed).

So, I guess my main question here is maybe would have a more graceful upgrade process?  It sometimes doesn't make sense to have the script removed from the gallery when waiting for approval.

Thanks!

Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've opened [an issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=177) a while ago regarding this (nearly 2 years now). You probably want to *star* it to keep track of updates.
About the approval process, it is not "reliable" as you could see. I had scripts that took 3 months to be re-approved and then, the next upgrade, only a couple of days.